# JSFiddle and other Live Code Services in New Tab

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks, tabs

Quite often, a user will use a service such as JSFiddle to demonstrate their point, and some answerers use it in return for a live demonstration of their code.

I'm not just talking about JSFiddle either, there are a number of services that allow links as part of a support to the OP's question or an answer.

Can these links open in a new window/tab?

I often find myself trying things in these services and testing code through a number of revisions and when I've finally solved the OP's issue, I have to use my back button to navigate through everything I've just done, just to post it back to them.

Yes, I could open in a new tab through browser functionality, but it's my own fault that I forget to do this all the time, I'm only human.

Is this possible?

Comment: See also: [Allow per user settings to open external links in the same or a new tab](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/168063)

Comment: [The Top 10 Web Design Mistakes](http://www.nngroup.com/articles/top-10-mistakes-web-design/)

Comment: As mentioned in my comment on your question @AlEverett, this isn't supposed to apply to every link as noted in those other posts, this is specific to supporting ones such as live code links. Obviously there's the problem of identifying different types of links but with a 'known/approved' list of Live Code links, this can be manageable.

Comment: Oh? Who's going to maintain that list?

Comment: `$("a[href^='http://jsfiddle.net/']").attr("target","_blank")`

Comment: "Code links only" is a very arbitrary distinction. Why would you open code links and not any other link a user puts in their post? Your own logic is that code links are "supporting" links, not "navigation" links; how are sources and references not "supporting" links? Any links in a question or answer are *required* to be there for the purpose of supporting that question/answer.

Comment: Ugh, don't play that juvenile "you mad" card. Nobody is "upset" by this.

Comment: @meagar I see your point. Though, often it'll be something I take from JSFiddle and put back into the question and after 32 revisions, that's a whole lot of 'Back' clicks. If your posting a link to some supporting evidence, chances are you'll click it, then read what the page says and return to the question quickly.

Comment: Aaaw, I have an actual answer to the question!  Vote to reopen!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, yes, a thousand times yes!  Do it yourself, though.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name       JSFiddle yourself in a new tab
// @namespace  http://statestreetgang.net/
// @version    0.1
// @description  Changes jsfiddle links so they open in a new tab
// @match      http://stackoverflow.com/q*
// @copyright  None! Suckmahbutt!
// ==/UserScript==


function exec(fn) {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.setAttribute("type", "application/javascript");
    script.textContent = '(' + fn + ')();';
    document.body.appendChild(script); 
    document.body.removeChild(script); 
}

window.addEventListener("load", function () {
    exec(function () {
        $("a[href^='http://jsfiddle.net/']").attr("target","_blank");
    });
});
```

Comment: -1 Not enough jQuery

Comment: You just made this didn't you! :)

Comment: @JoshC: what are you talking about?  It's all jquery!  there isn't any javascript in there!

Comment: @JoshC: (*"there isn't any javascript in there!"* is a joke, too)

Comment: Tested it and it works an absolute charm!

Comment: @danielhanly.com enjoy. Should have been one line, but for that annoying hack to get jquery working.

Comment: I'll mark yours as correct because the actual question is "Is this possible?" and you've shown me it is. Though SO doesn't support it, there is a solution.

Answer (score 11):

No, no, a thousand times no!

Don't force me to open a new window when clicking on a link. I can <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-click, middle-click, or right-click "Open in new window" if I desire.

Don't mess with the UX of basic browser functionality.

Comment: I understand with normal links, but my question is about Live Code links specifically, those links are used differently to normal ones, they're used to directly support the questions and answers on the site, often then referring right back to the post for an update.

Comment: @danielhanly.com Still, **no**. You have within you the power to open these links **however you want**. If you want them in a new tab, shift/ctrl/middle click and do it. You have the same ability on every website ever. Don't take away *my* ability to *not* open them in a new tab.

Comment: And how do you tell them apart?

Comment: We are developers, we use control click all the time :) 1+

Comment: When I go to my cable company's website to access online video or pay my bill, I end up with 6 tabs open from their target=_blanks. Ugh!

Comment: +1. I use middle-click all the time, and when I try to open a link in the same window and it opens a new tab I rage at the heavens. If I wanted a new tab, I would've F*!($ing opened a new gd tab.

Comment: There's a reason target=_blank was created. This would be a perfect use. Links to JSFiddle and SQLFiddle etc are used to support the page your on, not as a full navigate away. It's more of a supporting link not a navigation one

Comment: `target=_blank` sucks.. We will open a new tab if we want.. else there is always the back-button..

Comment: @JoshC I was intending to answer a JS Question previously, I ended up clicking the link to debug the code and running through loads and loads of revisions. I'd have to press back for all those page re-loads just to paste my answer back to the OP. It was annoying! I could have just closed the tab and been completely more efficient.

Comment: @danielhanly.com There *is* no perfect use for `target="_blank"`. It is used by website to *force* me to open a link in a new tab. Frankly, how I manage my tabbed browsing habits isn't the business of *any* website. It's completely up to the person browsing the site to choose how to open links. Do you not understand that you are already free to open up **any** link in a new tab yourself, by either ctrl-clicking or middle-clicking it? It costs you nothing to do so.

Comment: I suggest we add popups and stuff too then, I love those - they are great for UX..